# Convolution integral solution

Tags: integration, convolution

How would I solve the following convolution integral? I would normally be able to solve it if the $t-\tau$ is in the $h$ function, but it is in the exponential instead.
$$\int_0^te^{-\frac UB\lambda_L(t-\tau)}h(\tau)d\tau$$

Comment: You should pose your question with mathjax and not rely on pictures.  You should be more precise about what you are asking?  Are you evaluating an integral, or solving for some unknown? In the latter case you should state what the unknown is.  (You know, as in "solve for $x$"...)

Comment: I significantly edited your post to make it readable. Next time, make sure to include proper context, and write the equations here. (also, lambda is not $\tau$, it is $\lambda$.)

Comment: convolution is commutative, so you can put $t-\tau$ in $h$ instead and $\tau$ in the exponential

Comment: Presumably $h$ is the Heaviside step function, i.e. $h(t) = \mathsf 1_{[0,\infty)}(t)$?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and for editing my question, I apologise for any confusion. I am evaluating the integral. The given answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $h(\tau)=1$ for $\tau\in[0,t]$ and the exponential can be broken into two terms, one with $\tau$ and one without $\tau$. So
\begin{align}
\int_0^t e^{-\frac UB\lambda_L(t-\tau)}h(\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau &= \int_0^t e^{-\frac UB\lambda_Lt}e^{\frac UB\lambda_L\tau}\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= e^{-\frac UB\lambda_Lt}\int_0^t e^{\frac UB\lambda_L\tau}\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \frac B{U\lambda_L}e^{-\frac UB\lambda_Lt}\left(e^{\frac UB\lambda_Lt}-1\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much!